# Infinite Determinant between different Hilbert Spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is well-known, that if $A = \mathrm{id} + S$ is a bounded operator on a separable Hilbert Space $H$ with $S$ trace-class, then there is a well-defined notion of determinant, e.g. in terms of the singular value decomposition of $S$.

Now let $H$ and $K$ be two separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert Spaces. To define the determinant for operators between $H$ and $K$, one could now try to make the following definition.

**Def.** If for a bounded linear operator $A: H \longrightarrow K$, there exists a unitary transformation $U: H \longrightarrow K$ such that $A-U \in N(H, K)$, the space of nuclear operators from $H$ to $K$, define
$$ |\det(A)| = |\det(U^{-1}A)|.$$
Note that $U^{-1}A - \mathrm{id}$ is trace-class by the assumption on $A$ so that this makes sense.

*Question:* Is this well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $U$. A quick calculation shows that this boils down to the question:

**If $V^{-1}U-\mathrm{id}$ or equivalently $U-V$ is trace-class, is then necessarily $|\det(V^{-1}U)| = 1$ ?**

*Remark*: Notice that without some kind of orientation, you can obviously only define the modulus of the determinant. But is there a notion of orientability on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces?

Comment: The seminal paper on determinants of operators on infinite dimensional spaces is "Théorie de Fredholm" by Grothendieck in Bull. Soc. Math. France 84 (1956).  This could be of interest to you and is easily available online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this implies that $V^{-1}U$ can be diagonalised isn't it ?

Indeed: $V^{-1}U$ is a unitary, let just call it $W$. If $1-W$ is trace class it is in particular compact, moreover it is normal (as $W$ is unitary) hence it can be diagonalised in some Hilbert basis which obviously also diagonalize $W$.

The deteminant is then a convergent product of eigen values of $W$, which are all complex number of module $1$ so this conclude the proof.